# I agree that my question is a good fit for another site, but it's clear that it's on topic here too

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, closed-questions

According to the help center:

> Matters of Policy:
>
> Central to the idea of this site are the nuts and bolts of policies introduced by governments, presumably for the welfare of their citizens. As such, **asking about the tangible benefits and costs of legislation is on topic**

So while I agree that [my question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/26638/is-there-any-record-of-trickle-down-economics-improving-the-economy?noredirect=1#comment96964_26638) would be good on Economics.SE, I think according to this site's policy it's also on topic here and therefore shouldn't be closed.

Unless we decide to change your scope to exclude economic policy questions.

---

> Since the senate passed the tax bill this month that's left me
> confused. I try to look at both sides of partisan politics rather than
> joining one team and hating everything about the other. Now to
> understand whether this tax bill (which largely cut taxes for the
> rich) was something good for the country or not, I need to know if
> trickle down actually works.
>
> People on the Left swear it doesn't. But I'm looking for an objective,
> non partisan explanation of whether or not Trickle Down economics has
> been effective in the past. From what I understand it's been tried
> many times throughout history by now, as far back as the 1890s when it
> was called "horse and sparrow theory" according to Wikipedia, so it
> seems like we should have data to show whether or not it improves the
> economy.
>
> Is there any record of Trickle Down Economics improving the economy?

I'm specifically asking about "the tangible benefits and costs of legislation" as defined in your help center.

Answer (score 5):

We have already established in 2014 that [macroeconomics is in scope on this website](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/notice-macroeconomics-is-officially-in-scope). I therefor reopened the question (two other users already casted reopen votes at that point).

Answer (score 4):

The answer already posted by @Philipp confirms that macroeconomics is within scope here, but doesn't really explain how to resolve the situation when a question is legitimately on topic at two or more SEs. As such I'd argue it doesn't answer your question completely.

I did post a similar question to Meta.SE not long ago ([Is "closer match to another SE" a reason to close an on-topic question as off-topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303203/is-closer-match-to-another-se-a-reason-to-close-an-on-topic-question-as-off-to)), and the answer included this quote from [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/295232)

> We only migrate questions because they are off-topic on the original
>   site. It is perfectly possible for a question to be on-topic on
>   multiple sites, but that is not a reason to migrate it elsewhere,
>   unless the OP requests migration. As a general rule, if someone asks a
>   question here, and it's on-topic here, it should stay here.

So as general SE policy, if a question is on-topic where it is originally posted then it should not be closed as off-topic, and should not be migrated unless the poster requests migration.