# When the new economics beta begins, what questions will become out-of-scope for politics stack exchange?

Tags: discussion

The [second attempt](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61732/economics) at an *Economics* stack exchange is well on its way to a beta release<sup>1</sup>, fingers crossed.

Having read the [Politics vs Economics](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1465/2127) meta post and the macroeconomics [scoping](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1475/2127) statement; I believe close coordination between the two beta stacks will keep [politics out of economics](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18358/preventing-political-debates) and keep the drier economic theories out of politics.

Whilst I understand a desire to open *Politics.SE* up for economics questions; there will many out of scope - including many macroeconomic questions that are really the academics' raison d'être; or from questers that simply don't want politically sensitised answers to their question.

So the help page or some supplementary post will need to define a little more precisely what makes an economics question political enough stay here<sup>2</sup>. This way *economics.se* can migrate questions to *politics.se* and *politics.se* can migrate questions to *economics.se* with none falling through the cracks or blowing out into long commentary chains on either stack.

<sub>1. About a month or two away, give or take last minute definition refinement.</sub>
<sub>2. And I'll be the first to admit we can see pretty much everything through a political lens when we want to.</sub>

---

On a personal note, I hope *politics.se* doesn't poach any more economics questions than it needs to; as it'll make the initial growth period of the *economics.se* beta that much harder.

Comment: Shouldn't we wait until Economics makes it to beta first? I sincerely hope it does, but there aren't any guarantees that it will.

Comment: @YannisRizos Unless there's criteria above and beyond its current trajectory, I think it'll make it before the end of the year. After all, conditions to reach beta for the second economics proposal were set as more stringent and patient than the [first attempt](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/a/14594/94417). Additional [thought](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/q/11818/94417) has been put into this one. I ask now because shaping the politics side now whilst the economics proposal is in the commit stage allows for easier adjustment.

Comment: Wouldn't it heavily depend on what Economics scope will be (which won't be known fore real till at least start of public BETA)

Comment: @DVK Hmm up to a point, but the outlook and momentum when a beta starts is dependent on the engagement and considerations made in earlier stages. If there's scope bickering, best get something it done now so as not to distract from initial beta growth. That and whilst a bird in the hand is worth two in the bush, I'm pretty sceptical about forcing politics and economics together by way of seniority.

Comment: @LateralFractal - the usual approach is to NOT bicker - sites frequently have ontopic overlap. The only bickering is in the "we don't want your crap questions" area

Answer (score 2):

Based on nosing around on Economics.SE Private Beta's Meta, it seems to be extremely technical, with at least initial goal of having been restricted to grad student level and on Economics questions.

As such, I seriously doubt **any** Politics.SE qeustions would be ontopic there even if they concern Economics.

At best, any intersection would be asking advanced clarifications on Economy.SE from an economics argument cited on Politics.SE

Answer (score 0):

Politics shouldn't change a thing because any new site is created. It's up to the new site to determine their scope and what is acceptable and if the current politics definition cover all or almost all of their scope that's their problem.

Besides I would expect vastly different answers to a question about basic income on an Economics.SE than Politics.SE and both would be perfectly acceptable for their communities.

Comment: My point is, if we've widened our scope, should we at least assess the intent of the economics question before answering it here? They will get seriously different answers between stacks. Still, this meta question is somewhat out of date now as I now know that inter-beta coordination is actually quite limited (no migration paths, etc).