# When should a macro-economics post be posted here as opposed to economics stack exchange?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

Questions on macroeconomics are in scope both here on Politics and also on Economics:

See also:

- [Notice: Macroeconomics is officially in scope](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/notice-macroeconomics-is-officially-in-scope)
- [Politics vs Economics](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/politics-vs-economics?rq=1)
- https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macroeconomics

Some questions would be better here, and others on economics stack exchange. **What types of questions should you post here and what types of questions should you post there**?

See also [When the new economics beta begins, what questions will become out-of-scope for politics stack exchange?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1500/when-the-new-economics-beta-begins-what-questions-will-become-out-of-scope-for).

Comment: Is there a specific question you are asking about? Just because a question can be posted on a different stack exchange site doesn't mean it will not be on topic on others. Each question should be looked at on a case by case basis.

Comment: @JoeW so you can post the same exact question on multiple stack exchanges? Wouldn’t that make the domain of stack exchanges overlap? (Or is that supposed to happen)

Comment: No, you shouldn't post the exact same question on multiple stack exchanges. You just have the option to pick which one would be the best place for it if there are multiple places where it could be on topic. While most may be best on the econ site there are some that would be best on politics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my attempt to answer this question:

You should choose which site to ask your question on based on the kind of answer you're hoping to get, taking into account the users' fields of expertise.

So, a macroeconomics question posted on Economics.SE is going to get answered by people with an Economics background and is likely to be (on average) more mathematical and theoretical. The same question asked on Politics.SE is going to be answered by someone interested in politics, and answers are going to take more of a political angle: focusing, perhaps, more on the political implications of economics, or "economics as they work in the real-world" as opposed to theory.

One way to think about this is to ask yourself: "If I was at a University and I had this question, would I look for an economist or a political science professor?" Are you looking for an answer that quotes Economists, uses economic theory, and has equations? Then post on Economics. Are you looking for an answer that quotes politicians and pundits, that focuses more on the political implications, and, is, perhaps, a bit more "common-sense"? Then post on Politics.

Obviously, this isn't a real rule, but I think it's a good guideline.